# Layout changes no longer applied after animating a different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

What might cause changes made to a view programmatically to not be reflected on screen or even in debugging? For example, changing height or visibility of a view?

I'm seeing an issue where after one layout finishes animating, any changes I make to a different layout (height, child visibility, etc), no longer get applied.

In the image below, the sequence of events would be:

1. Show 1 is clicked to display "Hello World" in blue at the bottom.
2. Show 1 is clicked to hide "Hello World"
3. Show 2 is clicked to display "Goodbye World" in green/yellow at the bottom. Depending on the requested size, the height should be 50 or 100. When 100, there will be extra text.

> Note: this gif shows expected behavior, but the issue is described further below.

[image: layout display]

What I am seeing is that when adjusting the second layout using the code below, the changes do not appear on screen and will not appear in debugging, **but only if** the first layout is ever displayed. For example, if the code tries to change the height to 100, the layout will still appear as height 50 or vice versa. This also applies to the visibility of the `testHide` TextView where it will be set to `Gone` but appear as `Invisible`.

```
private void ButtonTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (layoutTwo.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
  {
    layoutTwo.StartAnimation(hide);
  }
  else
  {
    var layoutParams = layoutTwo.LayoutParameters;

    Random r = new Random();
    int coin = r.Next(2);

    if (coin == 0)
    {
      layoutParams.Height = 100;
      testHide.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
      layoutParams.Height = 50;
      testHide.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    }
    height.Text = "Height: " + layoutParams.Height;
    layoutTwo.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
    layoutTwo.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    layoutTwo.StartAnimation(show);
  }
  
  
}
```

ButtonOne_Click

```
private void ButtonOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (layoutOne.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
  {
    layoutOne.StartAnimation(hide);
  }
  else
  {
    layoutOne.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    layoutOne.StartAnimation(show);
  }
  
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="show 1"
  android:id="@+id/button1"/>
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Height:"
  android:id="@+id/height"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:text="show 2"
  android:id="@+id/button2"/>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:background="#123ABC"
  android:id="@+id/layout1">
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ABC123"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/layout2">
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:gravity="right"
  android:text="Goodbye World!" />
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:gravity="right"
  android:id="@+id/testHide"
  android:text="test hide" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Some things I have tried:

- Add/remove child view before animating
- Using `View.Post` to handle animation
- `View.Invalidate` before animation
- Assign new `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` object with MatchParent for width and the desired height.

I have also run a loop in a separate thread that monitors each view and confirmed the second layout's height was not being changed after displaying the first layout, but would be changed if the first layout was never displayed.

Comment: **Add to question** the xaml (or c#) that creates layoutOne and two, and their container. If nested, show containers starting at top of page. Its difficult to speculate what might need to change in the code you show, without seeing the elements being acted on. Ultimately, it is the layout that **contains** those layouts, which is responsible for allocating screen space for the two layouts. An issue that involves an interaction between those two, requires seeing what type of layout contains them, as well as `Horizontal/VerticalOptions` on the container (parent) and those two layouts.

Comment: added content_main.xml. The two LinearLayouts in question are children of a RelativeLayout.

Comment: ah, I missed that this is `Xamarin.Android`, not `Xamarin.Forms`. Sorry, I don't know details of Android layout. Maybe test without animations - directly hiding/showing the layouts. Do the layout heights update? Either way, might help zero in on what code to experiment with.

Comment: No problem. I did try it with and without animations and it results in the same behavior, so it likely might have to do more with the visbility of the view itself.

Comment: Is there any android call that will "invalidate" a view? Or force it to layout/redraw again?

Comment: Supposedely `view.invalidate()` would do that, but from what I have tested, it did not help in this case. The only thing that I have tried that seems to help is having a completely separate layout for when it needs to be larger or smaller, however, I still run into issues with visibility of certain views appearing as `Invisible` when I set them to `Gone`

Comment: What's the code of  `testHide`   `height`  `hide` and   `show` ? Could you please post the code of the full code of  `YourActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fully recreate your problem but based on code You have submitted I think something like this should work fine:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private LinearLayout layoutOne;
    private LinearLayout layoutTwo;
    private TextView testHide;
    private TextView height;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        layoutOne = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout1);
        layoutTwo = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout2);
        testHide = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.testHide);
        height = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.height);
        button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);

        button1.Click += ButtonOne_Click;
        button2.Click += ButtonTwo_Click;
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }


    private void ButtonOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Animation show = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.show);
        Animation hide = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.hide);

        if (layoutOne.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            layoutOne.StartAnimation(hide);
            layoutOne.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
        else
        {
            layoutOne.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            layoutOne.StartAnimation(show);
        }
    }

    private void ButtonTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Animation show = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.show);
        Animation hide = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.hide);

        if (layoutTwo.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            layoutTwo.StartAnimation(hide);
            layoutTwo.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
        else
        {
            var layoutParams = layoutTwo.LayoutParameters;

            Random r = new Random();
            int coin = r.Next(2);

            if (coin == 0)
            {
                layoutParams.Height = 100;
                testHide.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                layoutParams.Height = 50;
                testHide.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            height.Text = "Height: " + layoutParams.Height;
            layoutTwo.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            layoutTwo.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            layoutTwo.StartAnimation(show);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="show 1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Height:"
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="show 2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#123ABC"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ABC123"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:visibility="gone">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Goodbye World!" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/testHide"
                android:text="test hide" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Show Animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true" >
    <translate
      android:fromYDelta="100%p"
      android:toYDelta="0%p"
      android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Hide Animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true" >
    <translate
      android:fromYDelta="0%p"
      android:toYDelta="100%p"
      android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

[image: animation gif]